# NSString obtained from another class causes crash

Tags: iphone, memory-management, nsstring

*My iPhone application is `Tab based`. In a tab, say `Security Tab` I have three view controllers `First, Second, Third`. I am passing a string value to `Third` view controller from `Second` view controller. selectedAlertDesc is my NSString object of `Third` view controller.*

In `Third` view controller:

```
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *selectedAlertDesc;
@synthesize selectedAlertDesc = _selectedAlertDesc;
```

In `Second` view controller:

```
Third *controller = [[Third alloc] init];
[controller setSelectedAlertDesc:[[alertArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"alertDesc"]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
[controller release];
```

*It works fine, until I change the tab. If I leave the security tab in `Third` view controller page and come back after accessing some other tab, it crashes. It states, selectedAlertDesc became zombie.*

```
-[CFString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xeb3d760
```

*How can I solve this issue? I believe we should not initialize synthesized objects. Am I forgetting something here?*

**EDIT:**

*As suggested I used instruments for checking allocation/retain history. I got the following:- So after the usage of `selectedAlertDesc`, I retained it. Is it correct way to do?? And it works properly!!*

```
_selectedAlertDesc = [_selectedAlertDesc stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"opentag" withString:@"<"];
_selectedAlertDesc = [_selectedAlertDesc stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"closetag" withString:@">"];
[txtTxtVw setText:_selectedAlertDesc];
```

[image]

Comment: Two possibilities: make the property `copy` instead of `retain`; use Instruments and its Zombies template to look at the retain history for the object

Comment: have you implemented the constructor -(id)init in the implementation of "Third"

Comment: remove 
[controller release];

Comment: @Rupesh it is not related to it.. Anyways, tried it and still same err..

Comment: @AppleDelegate Should I implement??

Comment: @PhillipMills Copy didn’t work..

Comment: yes..else your allocation of the object wont happen from which the function is called

Comment: @PhillipMills - in case of immutable objects, like NSString, copy works as retain, because object cannot be changed.

Comment: @AppleDelegate I added the following code -(id)init {
    if ( self = [super init] ) {
        
        self.selectedAlertDesc = [[NSString alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
} 

It didn’t work either.. Am I missing something??

Comment: The retain history looks odd to me in that it doesn't mention any retain related to `setSelectedAlertDesc:`.  What does the line of code look like where the Zombie error is triggered?

Comment: Try turning all of `_selectedAlertDesc` into `self.selectedAlertDesc` so that you're making use of the property attributes.  Going straight to the iVar bypasses the retain/copy.

Comment: @PhillipMills It works, thank you :) Please post your answer, so then I can acknowledge it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

It turns out that the error is caused by code that directly assigns new values to an instance variable instead of using the `set...` method of the related property (or its corresponding dot notation).  This bypasses the property attributes and results in assignment of an autoreleased string.

(The primary clue is the missing entry in the Instruments retain history.)